# Bash grep JSON Response

Tags: json, bash, grep, jq

Here is the JSON Response in a File, namely, *RGLogin.json*

```
{"response":{"session_id":"2d48cc11ceabf28c9e92f4b677337dcd"},"response_status":200,"response_details":null}
```

The grep command below can retrieve *session_id*

```
grep -m1 -oP '\s*"session_id"\s*:\s*"\K[^"]+' RGLogin.json
```

But the following grep command can not retrieve response_status

```
grep -m1  -oP '\s*"response_status"\s*:\s*"\K[^"]+' RGLogin.json
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For session id, it is looking for quotes. For response status, it is not quoted.

```
grep -m1  -oP '\s*"response_status"\s*:\s*\K[^,]+' RGLogin.json
```

Comment: This solution is platform-specific. The `-P` option isn't available on BSD, macOS, or generally any other non-Linux operating system.

Answer (score 2):

ideologically, a correct way to resolve such asks would be to use tools which are aware of the data format. I.e. if it's JSON then json-aware tool must be used (and line-aware tools like `grep` should be use for linear/non-nested data structures).

E.g., for your JSON structure, to extract the required info using a walk-path unix tool for JSON: **[`jtc`](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc/blob/master/User%20Guide.md)**:

```
bash $ <RGLogin.json jtc -w'[response_status]'
200
bash $
```

Disclosure: I'm the creator of `jtc` tool

Answer (score 2):

grep is not the right tool for parsing JSON. Use [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) instead:

```
$ jq -r '.response_status' RGLogin.json
200
$
$ jq -r '.response.session_id' RGLogin.json
2d48cc11ceabf28c9e92f4b677337dcd
$
$jq -r '.response.session_id, .response_status' RGLogin.json
2d48cc11ceabf28c9e92f4b677337dcd
200
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer of @Dmitry

I use always the php interpreter for analyzing json data. But other script languages are possible too. Here is my bash/php solution to get both values:

```
#!/bin/bash

# define json string (get it from source)
json='{"response":{"session_id":"2d48cc11ceabf28c9e92f4b677337dcd"},"response_status":200,"response_details":null}'

# execute php script and eval the results
eval $( php <<- __EOT__
        <?PHP
        # php dollar sign must be escaped
        \$data = json_decode('$json');

        # print results in bash set-var format
        printf("session_id=\"%s\"\nresponse_status=\"%s\"\n",
                \$data->response->session_id,
                \$data->response_status );
        ?>
        # end-of-text marker must be placed at first column, 
        # or can be indented by real TABS (not SPACES).
__EOT__
        )

# show params in bash
echo "session_id      : $session_id"
echo "response_status : $response_status"
```

And the output is:

```
session_id      : 2d48cc11ceabf28c9e92f4b677337dcd
response_status : 200
```